# How can I proxy HTTP connections for URLs that involve port numbers

Tags: google-chrome, proxy

I have a setup where I can arrange access to a machine on a private network, on which I run an HTTP proxy which I access via an ssh tunnel (it only listens on localhost) to gain access to web applications that are only available on that network.

Although this works well generally, I've observed that this doesn't seem to work for URLs where the form of the URL is http://host.name:port/whatever ie. one that includes a port number.

The proxy server is tinyproxy, and I'm using the foxyproxy extension to Google Chrome to make it use the proxy server.

Is this a limitation of HTTP proxies in general, or could it be a problem with the browser/extension not using the proxy for all connections?

If it's a problem with the approach I'm taking, what alternative approach should I use instead?

Comment: sounds like you need a socks proxy, rather than one that focuses on HTTP/HTTPS operations. http://www.multiip.net/socks-proxy-http-proxy/

Comment: If you can expand on that with some information why, it'd make a reasonable answer

Answer (score 0):

Typically web proxies are by default only configured to utilize ports 80 & 443.  To proxy a request on a non-standard port (i.e. not 80 or 443) requires some form of manual configuration (if it is supported at all).  The manual configuration defines what port number is to be proxied and how to handle requests on the special port#.